# Having trouble with this method in c# wont clear variables

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to save current variables into list and then clear variables

```
    static void SaveInvoice(string name, string brand, double tireSize, double metalPrice, double donation, List<Customer> customerList)
    {
        //create object
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(name, brand, tireSize, metalPrice, donation);
        customerList.Add(newCustomer);
        Clear();
    }

    static void Clear()
    {

        string name = "No name";
        string brand = "No name";
        double metalPrice = 0;
        double tireSize = 0;
        double donation = 0;

    }
```

After storing to list display here

```
static void DisplayAllInvoices(List<Customer> customerList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe Right Speed Shop");
        Console.WriteLine("*************************");
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-15}{1,-15}{2,-15}{3,-15}{4,-15}", "Name", "Brand", "Tire", "Metal Price", "Donation");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1,-15}{2,-15}{3,-15}{4,-15}", "********", "********", "********", "************", "********");

        for (int i = 0; i < customerList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1,-15}{2,-15}{3,-15}{4,-15}", customerList[i].Name, customerList[i].Brand, customerList[i].TireSize, customerList[i].MetalPrice, customerList[i].Donation);
        }



    }
```

Comment: Please explain more. Are you aware that those variables you declared in the Clear method are **local** variables? They are only in scope inside that method. However, please explain what you wanted to accomplish, and what you observed instead. I am assuming you're asking because something is not behaving as you wanted it to, but you didn't write what you want and what it did.

Comment: Unrelated: `double metalPrice`  => do not use floating point types for monetary amounts.

Comment: _"and then clear variables"_ Why? If you tell us that, we can probably help you. Otherwise, it's not clear what your intent is.

Comment: Your method doesn't clear those variables, it creates new versions of them. And then immediately discards them..

Comment: The excessive use of `static` tells me, there may be an underlying lack of knowledge about how OOP works.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Clear()` method you actually create new variables that are scoped to this method itself. In other words, you just create five new variables local to the `Clear()` method.

Also, you cannot change the value of [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), like `double` inside a function (you can, but it will not propagate back in the enclosing scope).
You can do this for [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), like a `string` but it's not a good practice (in most cases).
Why do you need to clear these values?
In my view you don't need the `Clear()` method. You just call the
`SaveInvoice` with new values any time you want and it will add a customer to the list (given that the `customerList` is defined).

Answer (score 0):

Your code have some troubles. Read the comments:

```
static void SaveInvoice(string name, string brand, double tireSize, double metalPrice, double donation, List<Customer> customerList)
{
    // You create newCustomer in this static method and store in the list. 
    // After that, you never use newCustomer. You don't need clear
    Customer newCustomer = new Customer(name, brand, tireSize, metalPrice, donation);
    customerList.Add(newCustomer);

    // To clear newCustomer, you need use newCustomer Clear method, not a static method
    newCustomer.Clear();
}

// You must remove static to work with your instance
void Clear()
{
    // Then, you can use "this" properties
    this.name = "No name";
    this.brand = "No name";
    this.metalPrice = 0;
    this.tireSize = 0;
    this.donation = 0;
}
```

But be carefull. If you invoke Clear, you clear the newCustomer properties and this object is stored in your list. So your List item will have that properties cleared. I think you only need, the new and Add, without use Clear method.